# How to create a calculated column in mysql which calculate date from timestamp column having varchar type

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I'm stuck in a big problem. I want to create a calculated column in an existing table having a column name `LS_TimeStamp` of `Varchar(20)` type which store both date and time in format `(0000-00-00 . 00:00:00)` and I want a calculated column which extract only date from that column and stores in 'Date' column which is also a `Varchar(20)` type.

Comment: You want a 'Date' column, which stores a date, but is a VARCHAR?!

Comment: yes, is there any problem if i have a varchar type?

Comment: A date in a VARCHAR field will work only most of the time, take more space, and not have any benefit. Use the DATE type and create 2 triggers to set the field as @AlmaDoMundo suggested.